# NDSolve inside Module with local variables

Tags: scoping

I want to use NDSolve within a Module and output the solution at some times. (Mathematica 10)

All works fine with global variables (symbols)

```
p[times_List, {k1_, k2_, k3_, k4_}] := Module[{eq},
 eq = {
  m'[t] == -(k2 + k3) m[t] + k1 i[t] + k4 p[t],
  i'[t] == k2 m[t] - k1 i[t],
  p'[t] == k3 m[t] - k4 p[t],
  m[0] == 1, i[0] == 0, p[0] == 0};
 sol = NDSolve[eq, {i[t], m[t], p[t]}, {t, 0, tlist[[-1]]}][[1]];
 pop[t_] = {i[t], m[t], p[t]} /. sol;
 pop /@ times
]
```

Here an example:

```
p[Range[0, 5], {1, 1, 2, 3}]
```

The output is:

```
{{0., 1., 0.}, {0.312093, 0.404352, 0.283556}, {0.360173, 0.381508, 
 0.25832}, {0.371482, 0.376543, 0.251976}, {0.374165, 0.375366, 
 0.250469}, {0.374802, 0.375087, 0.250111}}
```

But with local variables (symbols)

```
p[[times_List, {k1_, k2_, k3_, k4_}] := Module[{eq, t, pop, m, i, p, sol},
 eq = {
  m'[t] == -(k2 + k3) m[t] + k1 i[t] + k4 p[t],
  i'[t] == k2 m[t] - k1 i[t],
  p'[t] == k3 m[t] - k4 p[t],
  m[0] == 1, i[0] == 0, p[0] == 0};
 sol = NDSolve[eq, {i[t], m[t], p[t]}, {t, 0, tlist[[-1]]}][[1]];
 pop[t_] = {i[t], m[t], p[t]} /. sol;
 pop /@ times
]
```

it does not work anymore:

```
p[Range[0, 5], {1, 1, 2, 3}]
```

The output is:

```
{{i$18625[0], m$18625[0], p$18625[0]}, {i$18625[1], m$18625[1], 
    p$18625[1]}, {i$18625[2], m$18625[2], p$18625[2]}, {i$18625[3], 
    m$18625[3], p$18625[3]}, {i$18625[4], m$18625[4], 
    p$18625[4]}, {i$18625[5], m$18625[5], p$18625[5]}}
```

Any ideas why this is not working like that? Thank you.

Comment: Use this form: `sol = NDSolve[eq, {i, m, p}, {t, 0, 5}][[1]]`, i.e., `m` instead `m[t]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Source of the problem.** The problem arises because the symbol `t` is localized two different times in two different ways, once in `Module` and once in the definition of `pop`.  Below is a simplified example, with only a single function being solved for, but the same thing happens for OP's system.  I print out the form of the solution `sol` and the definition of `pop` to show the mismatch of the two symbols represented by `t` in the code.  The mismatch means that the solution is not substituted for `x[t]` in the definition of `pop`.  Because the body of the definition of `pop` depends on `Module` variables, the function parameter `t` is remaned `t$`.  As it says in the tutorial, [Variables in Pure Functions and Rules](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/VariablesInPureFunctionsAndRules.html), *Mathematica* does this more liberally than is strictly necessary.  Because of this, we have `x$311828[t$]` in the body of `pop` and `x$311828[t$311828]` in rule in `sol`, and they do not match.

```
p[times_List, {k1_, k2_, k3_, k4_}] := 
 Module[{eq, t, pop, x, sol}, 
  sol = NDSolve[{x'[t] == x[t], x[0] == 1}, {x[t]}, {t, 0, 5}][[1]];
  Print[sol];
  pop[t_] = {x[t]} /. sol;
  Print[Definition[pop]];
  pop /@ times]

p[Range[0, 5], {1, 1, 2, 3}]

(*
  {x$311828[t$311828] -> InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 5.}}, <>][t$311828]}
*)
(*
  Attributes[pop$311828]={Temporary}

  pop$311828[t$_]={x$311828[t$]}
*)
(*
  {{x$311828[0]}, {x$311828[1]}, {x$311828[2]}, {x$311828[3]}, {x$311828[4]}, {x$311828[5]}}
*)
```

Personally, I have come to prefer to call `NDSolve` in the form

```
NDSolve[eqns, x, {t, 0, 5}]
```

with `x` instead of `x[t]`, and this is a way to solve the OP's problem.  [`NDSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NDSolveValue.html) is an attractive alternative, but I have come to prefer to keep the symbolic expressions and equations separate from the approximate solutions.  The call above produces a rule of the form

```
  {x -> InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 5.}}, <>]}
```

which replaces a head `x` in `x[t]` or `x[1.2]` by a function, which will automatically evaluate if the argument is a number.  This means that it does not matter how `t` is localized; the substitution will work.

**Changing one line fixes the code.**  Replace the `NDSolve` line with this:

```
 sol = NDSolve[eq, {i, m, p}, {t, 0, tlist[[-1]]}][[1]];
```

**Further remarks.**  There are several advantages to using `NDSolve` this way.  The main disadvantage is writing `/. sol` a lot.

One advantage is that the symbol `x` (or `i`, `m`, and `p`) remains undefined and can be used for symbolic manipulation and analysis.

The substitution `/. sol` works on derivatives, `x'[t]` etc., which is awkward to accomplish if the rule is in the form `x[t] -> ...`.

You can check the residuals to see how good the solution is.  For instance,

```
eq /. Equal -> Subtract /. sol /. t -> RandomReal[{0, 5}, 10]
```

or one can use `Table` or `NIntegrate` instead of random sampling.

Plotting is just as easy, and if the integration stops early and you don't know the domain exactly, you can get it out of `sol`:

```
Plot[Evaluate[x[t] /. sol], Evaluate[Flatten[{t, x["Domain"] /. sol}]]
```

Comment: Thank you Michael E2 for your workaround and for the detailed explanation.

Comment: @dnet  You're welcome.