# How to plot InterpolatingFunction across its domain

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, interpolation

I'm using `NDSolve` to solve a system of coupled ODEs for a range of different parameters. For most points in the parameter space, the integration breaks down prematurely. However, I would still like to plot the resulting `InterpolatingFunction`s up to the point where `NDSolve` broke down.

Of course, that point `NDSolve` changes based on the chosen parameters so I find myself constantly having to adjust the plot bounds manually.

It seems to me that there should be an easier way. Can I tell Mathematica to simply plot an `InterpolatingFunction` for all values inside the domain (i.e. without using extrapolation)?

Comment: One way is given here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/134222/easy-way-to-plot-ode-solutions-from-ndsolve

Comment: 2nd way: See the last three lines of this answer: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/65090/4999

Comment: @MichaelE2 Regarding option 1: Can I somehow modify the interpolating function `ipf` within `(List)LinePlot`? Say I consider `ipf` a function of $x$, can I somehow listlineplot `ipf[x] e^x`? Also, `ListLinePlot` seems to stop just before the point where `NDSolve` broke down; the plot it gives looks completely regular. But when I copy the last point from `NDSolve`'s output into a `Plot` range, I see a singularity.

Comment: @MichaelE2 The same issue of Mathematica excluding singular points happens with the second option. Do you know how I can prevent this?

Comment: I don't think so.  `ListPlot[if]` seems a special case, and it just connected the interpolated points with (straight) lines.  For other kinds of plots use `Plot[]` with `if["Domain"]` as in the 2nd way (or MikeY's answer). -- "`ListLinePlot` seems to stop": I'm not sure what you're seeing, but it could be due to automatic plot range adjustments. This would be the case if `NDSolve` stopped because the solution was going to infinity. Did you try `ListLinePlot[if, PlotRange -> All]`?

Comment: @MichaelE2 I did try `PlotRange -> All`; no change. What I see when copying the last point in the domain: Imagine a plot dropping off continuously and suddenly exploding to infinity where `NDSolve` broke down. When I use `ListLinePlot` without explicit domain I get the same plot except that it stops just before the singularity. However, when examining the output I'd like to be able to see such features.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I also tried `Exclusions -> None` when using `Plot` and `if["domain"]` but that didn't help either.

Comment: Do you have an example I can see? This does not seem to have that problem: `foo = NDSolve[{y'[x] == y[x]^2, y[0] == 1}, y, {x, 0, Infinity}]; ListLinePlot[y /. foo]`.

Comment: It's also possible that the value of the solution became complex. (It's still just a shot in the dark.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60320/discussion-between-casimir-and-michael-e2).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want the domain of your interpolating function. You can get this easily. Creating an `InterpolatingFunction[ ]` with domain `{0,100}` ...

```
hh = h /. NDSolve[{h'[x] == x, h[0] == 0}, h, {x, 0, 100}][[1]];
```

Then extract it

```
hh["Domain"]

(* {{0., 100.}} *)
```

directly use as a plot range:

```
Plot[hh[x], Evaluate@{x, Sequence @@ First@hh["Domain"]}]
```